# Print messages in kernel module using c++

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, cout

I am editing a kernel module written in C++. I want a function to print a message but i guess i can not use `cout` or any Standard Input/Output Streams library function because the module resides in kernel space.

I have tried to include the `iostream` library:

```
....
#include <iostream>
....
```

When i compile with `g++` i get:

```
 error: iostream: No such file or directory
 error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: The Linux kernel doesn't have any C++ runtime-library support.

Comment: I have tried to use `kprintf` and i get error `'kprintf' was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel does not support C++ very well at all, and you can't use the `<iostream>` - I suspect any of the STL is also completely out of the question, but it's been quite some time since I looked at C++ in Linux kernel mode.

The standard implementation of `cout` and `cerr` are using OS features, which of course won't work inside the kernel. So you mustn't use those. It would of course be possible to implement something that works the same way (call it `kostream`), and `kostream& operator<<(kostream& os, sometype value)`, which produces some output into a buffer, then use `printk` or some of the primitives that `printk` uses to produce the actual output.

No matter whether it is C or C++, you will eventually end up using `printk` (or it's constituent parts) to print things in the Linux kernel.

Note that using `fstream` or `stringstream` is also not going to work inside the kernel.

Comment: `iostreams` is definitely out of the question.  The STL containers might be possible provided you used custom allocators rather than the default (`std::allocator`).  You'll also need to work out what to do with exceptions and then, if you get this to work, expect a tirade of abuse from Linus.

Comment: Is the problem just a missing `new/malloc`?

Answer (score 3):

Use **printk** api for printing message

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "*** This is a debug message only. ***\n");
```

You can check print messages of your kernel module to dmesg

Comment: I have tried with printk and i get error 'printk' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: You have to include #include <linux/kernel.h> #include <linux/module.h> in your source